# Can't back to previous activity after handle push

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

My handler push notification:

```
class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
//  some code handler
// show push notification and set tap handler
      PushNotificationService.showNotification(applicationContext, payloadData["title"]!!, payloadData["body"]!!)
}
```

and here show push

```
object PushNotificationService {
    val CHANNEL_ID = "channelId"
    val NOTIFICATON_ID = 1

    fun showNotification(context: Context, title: String, body: String) {
        val intent = Intent(context, InvitationDetailsActivity::class.java).apply {
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context), {
            this.notify(NOTIFICATON_ID, builder.build())
        })
    }
```

And when server send message it's success show on the notification area. And when I tap it's success open my activity `InvitationDetailsActivity`.
Nice. But the  problem is that all previous activities delete. And when I back press on `InvitationDetailsActivity` it's exit from app.
But I need to go for previous activity.

Test case:

```
1. Start app
2. Open activity MyActivty1
3. Tap push
4. Open InvitationDetailsActivity
5. Press back
6. Open activity MyActivty1
```

Comment: whats the launchmode of InvitationDetailsActivity?

Comment: @ShaluTD standard launchermode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent Notification from clearing all activities in the back stack, you must set up a Special Activity `PendingIntent`. A special activity doesn't need a back stack. Please try the below code while creating the `PendingIntent`.

```
 val notifyIntent = Intent(this, InvitationDetailsActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or 
     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
val notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
```

In `Manifest`, set up the activity as below:-

```
<activity
    android:name=".InvitationDetailsActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

For more info on this, please check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html)